# Assembly "BouncyCastle.Crypto" was built using version v1.1.4322 of the .NET Framework. SQL Server currently uses version v4.0.30319

Tags: sql-server

1. I am trying to add the `BouncyCastle.Crypto` in sql server 2012.
2. my BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll version is 1.8.1

Error :

> Assembly "BouncyCastle.Crypto" was built using version v1.1.4322 of
>   the .NET Framework. SQL Server currently uses version v4.0.30319.

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: Do you mark the assembly as UNSAFE?

Comment: If i mark it as UNSAFE its working fine but i need to add Assembly in safe permission set. what changes need to do to set as safe